# Access the same data by more than 1 client on almost the same time

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-2008-r2, locking

Good day all,

I am work on C# .net 4.0 framework, and database is microsoft SQL server 2008 R2.

There is a system to let user do gift redemption. When User click on the "redeem" button, system will :

1. check on the gift inventory first before update customer_gift table,
2. and update the gift_inventory table for the particular gift.

If the inventory is less than 0, then it will prompt error message to tell user that the gift is already finish, and then cancel the redemption process.

There is a problem happen in the following condition :

Gift A only have 1 quantity in inventory now.

Customer Jack click on "redeem" button at `2013-11-11 09:22:27.780`.
Customer Jess click on "redeem" button at `2013-11-11 09:22:27.497`.

The different time they click on "redeem" button is only 0.0283 seconds.

Thus, maybe the different time is too short, both of them was successful redeem the gift because, before the system (first customer) update the gift_inventory table, the system (second customer) already get the data from inventory (Gift A), thus, system still let second customer to proceed because the inventory is still equal to 1.

I have think out of a way to solve this problem, which is describe as follow :
Create a new column for the gift_inventory table, name `lock`, with data type `Boolean` . When customer clicked on the redeem button, and before the system check the gift inventory, set the Boolean to `true`. Thus, if the second customer, try to access to the gift inventory, and found that the `lock` = `true`, then system will wait for 1 seconds and then try to access again, until the `lock` = `false`, then only access and get the inventory data.

However, I dun think this is a good solution. I think this may cause the database become slow.

Any idea and suggestion?

Comment: In a word: "Transactions" - google for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this just by doing each update in a transaction and by using row locking in database.

Read more here:

**Transactions**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598.aspx

**Locking**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: +1 The key thing is you are locking inside the database, not inside the client program like in the OP's suggestion at the bottom of the question.